# Tlmgr works but nothing was installed

Tags: installing, texlive

I just installed the latest version of Texlive 2011 from the iso; everything is fine, even **tlmgr** it's ok except the fact that it can't install new packages from the repository.

```
root@tux-laptop:~# tlmgr update -list
tlmgr: package repository http://ftp.uniRoma2.it/TeX/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2011/tlpkg/backups
skipping forcibly removed package l3packages
tlmgr: no updates available
root@tux-laptop:~# tlmgr search fourier
 engrec - Enumerate with lower- or uppercase Greek letters.
 fourier - Using Utopia fonts in LaTeX documents.
 fouriernc - Use New Century Schoolbook text with Fourier maths fonts.
 pst-func - PSTricks package for plotting mathematical functions.
 pxgreeks - Shape selection for PX fonts Greek letters.
 trfsigns - Typeset transform signs.
 txgreeks - Shape selection for TX fonts Greek letters.
 utopia - Adobe Utopia fonts.
root@tux-laptop:~# tlmgr show fourier
package:     fourier
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Using Utopia fonts in LaTeX documents.
longdesc:    Fourier-GUTenberg is a LaTeX typesetting system which uses Adobe Utopia as its standard base font. Fourier-GUTenberg provides all complementary typefaces needed to allow Utopia based TeX typesetting, including an extensive mathematics set and several other symbols. The system is absolutely stand- alone: apart from Utopia and Fourier, no other typefaces are required. The fourier fonts will also work with Adobe Utopia Expert fonts, which are only available for purchase. Utopia is a registered trademark of Adobe Systems Incorporated
installed:   Yes
revision:    15878
cat-version: 1.3
cat-date:    2008-12-13 14:57:21 +0100
cat-license: lppl
collection:  collection-fontsextra

root@tux-laptop:~# tlmgr install fourier
tlmgr: package repository http://ftp.uniRoma2.it/TeX/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

Ok, what's wrong with tlmgr? When i try to compile a new document which uses the newly installed package, pdflatex can't find it.

Comment: If you mean the PATH yes i did it, otherwise i couldn't even run tlmgr like i was able to do in the report

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, it was tricky but i found out that some executable from the past installation of texlive were still installed on my system and this perl script, aka **tlmgr**, is probably not able to identify and make a distinction between executables that belongs to a texlive environment instead of another.

It's not my case but in another situation maybe the tool **ldd** could also be really helpful in a GNU/Linux environment, and remember that most of this "programs" that come with texlive are scripts and not executables.

Comment: so...how'd you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `tlmgr` was interruputed.  Try `mktexlsr` as root and then check that `kpsewhich` can find `fourier.sty`:

```
boris@somewhere:~$ kpsewhich fourier.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fourier/fourier.sty
```

Comment: nothing, the output of kpsewhich is empty; considering the ouput of tlmgr while performing the installation looks like it download nothing. I do not have any clues right now ...

Comment: i just notice that TEXMFCNF is not setted and pratically no environments variables were created during the installation process. What are the environment variables needed by tex?

Comment: Normally no environmental vars are set: texlive binaries are expected to read everything from the files at startup.  Based on your input. I'd reinstall texlive from scratch: something definitely went wrong.

Comment: I installed texlive from a directory generated from the iso unpacked with an archive tool running the script install-tl as sudo, there is a better way to install texlive?

Comment: What does `tlmgr conf` say?

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/BUh5Exh3)

Comment: I solved it, i made a separate post to explain this.