# TeXworks doesn't see packages installed by tlmgr

Tags: packages, installing, texworks

I am running Fedora 19 on a Dell Latitude E6410 with an i7 dual-core. The program I use for LaTeX is TeXworks. I have Tex Live 2013, and use pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 set as my processing tool under preferences.

I would like to use the package "pgfplots.sty" in TeXworks, but TeXworks tells me

> ! LaTeX Error: File `pgfplots.sty' not found.

This question has been asked several times, but I have not found an answer. For each of the things I have tried, the explanation includes a link to the answer(s) suggesting that solution.

I have checked, and TeXworks is [running TeX Live 2013](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132200/installed-sty-with-tlmgr-but-latex-cant-find-it):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
```

I have set up tlmgr and have run the commands to install the package:

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# tlmgr install pgfplots
tlmgr: package repository http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
[root@localhost Desktop]# tlmgr update pgfplots
tlmgr: package repository http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no updates available
```

tlmgr has downloaded the package into the correct location:

```
[beason4251@localhost ~]$ kpsewhich pgfplots.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty
```

I have [run mktexlsr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34506/tlmgr-works-but-nothing-was-installed) and it ran successfully.

```
[root@localhost ~]# mktexlsr
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-local/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
```

tlmgr tells me [the package is installed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133407/see-which-files-are-installed-when-installing-a-package-with-tlmgr), output linked below:

[beason4251@localhost Desktop]$ [tlmgr info pgfplots --list](http://pastebin.com/74LBsXdp)

If I run the command

```
pdflatex M365CNotes.tex
```

everything works fine and the pdf is created, I just can't do the same through TeXworks.

Here are my [typesetting preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMt5h.jpg). The duplicate entry at the bottom is one I added manually while trying to get this to work. I've removed it now.

I can't link to the output of the following document since I don't have enough reputation yet:

```
\RequirePackage{array}\stop
```

Here's a disassembled link: http: //pastebin. com/Zgxt2s6R

Comment: Sounds like you have two TeX systems installed and TeXworks is finding a different one to TL2013. What do the typesetting preferences show?

Comment: All right, added to the original post. TeXworks is definitely looking in the correct place The folder /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux matches up with the output from mktexlsr.

Comment: Can you try compiling from TeXworks a one line file containing `\RequirePackage{array}\stop` and reporting the log file?

Comment: Sure! Here's the link: http://pastebin.com/Zgxt2s6R

Comment: @beason4251 You find the line `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty` which shows that TeXworks uses a different TeX distribution. You should check that you have the correct path at the top in the “Typesetting” tab of the preferences window.

Comment: Thanks! Just added the correct version of pdfLaTeX and now it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.log` file resulting from compiling the suggested one line document

```
\RequirePackage{array}\stop
```

shows

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) (format=pdflatex 2013.8.14)  25 SEP 2013 17:41
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
[...]
```

and the line

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
```

definitely tells you that TeXworks is not using the “vanilla” TeX Live 2013 rooted in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013
```

but a system provided one. Installing packages with `tlmgr` has no effect on the TeX distribution presently used by your TeXworks.

Open the Preferences window of TeXworks and go to the “Typesetting” tab. You find at the top a list of the search paths for executable programs. Ensure that

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux
```

is at the top.

Indeed TeXworks doesn't use the `PATH` environment variable or, better, it supplements it with its own list of paths as ordered in the Preferences.

Here's a picture of the window taken from a Mac OS X machine, but it should be similar on your system. The buttons for adding or moving a path should be self-explaining.

[image]

Comment: Yup, I just had to add the correct executable of pdfLaTeX and now it works.