# pdflatex not seeing tlmgr packages

Tags: pdftex, tlmgr

I have a feeling that the version of `pdflatex` that I'm using is not seeing the packages installed by `tlmgr`, though it might also be that `tlmgr` is not installing packages correctly. I don't know how to point `pdflatex` to the correct path, so help with that would be really welcome!

Currently, when I check the paths of `pdflatex` and `tlmgr`, I get:

```
Agness-MacBook-Pro-1166:thesis-latex agnes$ which pdflatex
/opt/local/bin/pdflatex
Agness-MacBook-Pro-1166:thesis-latex agnes$ which tlmgr
/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin//tlmgr
```

When I run `pdflatex test.tex`, I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/MacPorts 2018.47642_8) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.

! LaTeX Error: File `tufte-handout.cls' not found.
```

And when I run `tlmgr install tufte-latex` (`tufte-handout.cls` is a file within that repository), I get:

```
tlmgr: package repository http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr install: package already present: tufte-latex
```

I've tried multiple variations on

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin//tlmgr
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin
```

etc, and followed the install instructions (+ path-adding) on the texLive website. None seem to work!

I also read the solution in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135059/texworks-doesnt-see-packages-installed-by-tlmgr) but, while this might be the issue, there was no clue as to how to configure `pdflatex` itself, as that person was struggling with TexWorks. Even when I manually paste the package into the folder and add it to the path, `pdflatex` doesn't see it: it works when i copy-paste individual files into the same repository, but this is silly!

The only thing that makes me think it might be a `tlmgr` not a path problem is that when I search my computer (for e.g. `tufte-handout.cls`), it returns no results (this is with hidden files showing, searching the whole computer).

Any help very welcome!

Comment: the .cls file should be in the master system ~wherever/ `texmf/tex/latex/tufte-latex` folder along with the other cls bst and .def so if it is there then perhaps it is the texmf root not set right but ensure running texhash gets it registered first what looks odd to me is the //before tlmgr in most sytems that path to binaries would be unterminated for a single slash to be apended

Comment: ah -- somewhat mysteriously solved by adding the same path I'd tried to add in the cli directly to `~/.bash_profile`. If anyone's having the same issue, I added the line `export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin:$PATH"` directly to the end of `~/.bash_profile`. It might be that I had a typo when I tried it in the command line. Thanks for your help KJO! It does indeed look mysterious, though, now it works so less concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding the line `export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin:$PATH"` directly to the end of `~/.bash_profile`. It might be that I had a typo when I tried it in the command line.

Comment: If you installed the TeX Live 2018 Distribution using the MacTeX installer prepend the PATH variable with `/Library/TeX/texbin` rather than the direct path to the TeX Live 2018 binaries. That way if you install TeX Live 2019, once it comes out, via the MacTeX-2019 installer package it will automatically have that on you default PATH. You will also easily be able to switch between TeX Live 2018 and 2019 if you run into a problem using the TeX Live Utility supplied with MacTeX (in /Applications/TeX).

Comment: really helpful, thanks!

Comment: If only 900 other posts on the internet talked about PATH instead of indicating the need to install packages with `tlmgr` this would have save me 20 minutes.  Thanks for this.  Please accept this answer.

Comment: ah! I think when i made this post I didn't have enough reputation to do that. glad it helped :)

Comment: This saved my day, thanks!